# How can I access to LiveData related object outside the observer?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm making an app that uses room and Livedata to store and display data, I can create and delete single items without the problem, But I'm struggling to create a process to update values.

The problem is that I need to access an object related to the LiveData object outside the observer to change the object values and update it using the view model, But when I try using LiveData.value I always get a null outside the observer and a valid object inside the observer (I show this using a toast and snack back as you can see in the code below).

So, How can I access or update an object related to the LiveData outside the observer?

```
    if(intent.hasExtra("MEDICINE_ID")){
        title = getString(R.string.editar_medicamento)
        medicamentoActualLive = medicamentoViewModel.getMedicamento(intent.getIntExtra("MEDICINE_ID",-1))
        medicamentoActualLive.observe(this, android.arch.lifecycle.Observer {
            CampoNombreComercial.setText(it!!.nombreMedicamento,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
            CampoNombreGenerico.setText(it!!.nombreGenerico,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
            CampoDosis.setText(it!!.dosis,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
            CampoNota.setText(it!!.nota,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)

            val MedicineTypeIndex =  this.resources.getStringArray(R.array.TipoMedicamento).indexOf(it!!.tipo)
            SpinnerTipoMedicamento.setSelection(MedicineTypeIndex)

            MedicamentoIconoTV.setColorFilter(it.color!!)

            mCurrentPhotoPath = it.fotografia!!
            displayPic()

            medicamento = it
            Toast.makeText(this@AnadirMedicamentoActivity,"El valor del medicamento live es: " + medicamento.nombreGenerico, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })

        Snackbar.make(LayoutConstrain,"El valor del medicamento live externo: " + medicamentoActualLive.value?.nombreGenerico, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }else{
        title = getString(R.string.AnadirMedicamento)
    }
```

The save or update process is made in this function called in the onClick method of a floating action button:

```
private fun saveMedicineToDB(medicamento: Medicamento){
    if(intent.hasExtra("USER_ID")){
        medicamentoViewModel.update(medicamento)

    }else{
        medicamentoViewModel.insert(medicamento)
    }
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
    finish()
}
```

Comment: You don't, because queries are loaded asynchronously.

Comment: So, is there some way to do the query, keep the object and change later and update it with the view model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem, as the comments says I can't access to the LiveData object data due the asynchronously query, but I can access from a UI event (onClick event in this case), This is my solution:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val establecimiento : Establecimiento

    if(intent.hasExtra("ESTABLISHMENT_ID")){
        establecimiento = establecimientoActualLive.value!!
    }else{
        establecimiento = Establecimiento(0)
        val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this@AnadirEstablecimientoActivity)

        val usuarioID = sharedPref.getInt("actualUserID",-1)
        establecimiento.usuarioID = usuarioID

    }
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.itemSave -> {
            establecimiento.nombre  = NombreEstablecimientoTV.text.toString()
            establecimiento.tipo = tipoEstablecimiento
            establecimiento.direccion = DireccionEstablecimientoTV.text.toString()
            establecimiento.telefono1 = Telefono1EstablecimientoTV.text.toString()
            establecimiento.telefono2 = Telefono2EstablecimientoTV.text.toString()
            establecimiento.email = EmailEstablecimientoTV.text.toString()
            establecimiento.sitioWeb = SitioWebEstablecimeintoTV.text.toString()
            establecimiento.latitud = latitud
            establecimiento.longitud = longitud


            if(establecimiento.usuarioID != -1){

                saveEstablishmentToDB(establecimiento)
            }

            return true
        }
        android.R.id.home -> {
            onBackPressed()
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is from Livedata.java

```
static final Object NOT_SET = new Object();
```

...

```
public T getValue() {
    Object data = mData;
    if (data != NOT_SET) {
        return (T) data;
    }
    return null;
}
```

....

```
/**
* Creates a LiveData with no value assigned to it.
*/
public LiveData() {
    mData = NOT_SET;
    mVersion = START_VERSION;
}
```

So if the Livedata Object was not modified it will return null